# Mesh does not match UV mapping,

Tags: mesh, uv, faces, normal-map

I am trying to map the face of my mesh but I don't see any change even when I move the quads all the way around. Nothing I do in the UV Map gets reflected on the actual mesh.

Does anyone know why is that and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Hello maybe you have created a second uv map, check the Object Data panel > UV Maps and select the good one?

Comment: You are totally right. I found it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a second UV map, check the *Object Data panel > UV Maps* and select the good one:

[image]